# Favorites tab is showing different number than what is highlighted in list

Tags: support, statistics, bookmarks, caching

The number of highlighted questions in the list is different than the one shown in the *Favorites* tab.

Sometimes I get 1 favorite in the tab, but no highlighted question. In this case, I get 4 favorites in the tab header, but 5 questions are highlighted.

[image: Screenshot of favorites tab]

Why is it not equal? What are the differences? Is it just a caching/timing issue?

**EDIT**

As response to the new answer by @TylerH,
Even **for this question** I get number 6 in tab although I got only 1 new answer (which I already read) 
[image]

**EDIT 2**

I found a case where no highlight questions but favorites number is 1 ( no new answer is seen)

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Today I found that I can have no favorites number with 8 highlighted questions!

[image]

**EDIT 4**

Today there were a number 4 in favorites with 2 highlighted questions which were updated 1 or 2 days ago so it shouldn't be highlighted :

[image]

**EDIT 5**

Now Number is 10 and 1 highlighted questions, I'm starting to think the problem can be caused by one of two options : favorite my own question and/or using browser in mobile and web (maybe in web it isn't updated with mobile hits)

[image]

**EDIT 6**

I'm 99% sure that each delete comment increase by 1 the number indicator while if deleted 3 comments in question, it'll highlight only 1 question.

Still waiting to know how highlights can be more than the number indicator

[image]

Comment: My guess is - but I cannot test it very well, as I don't really use the favorites - that a question is highlighted until you've actually visited the question. The badge in the tab on the other hand is cleared immediately.

Comment: No, highlight is remove after refresh tab

Comment: The number and the highlighting mean different things: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114274/what-does-highlighting-mean-on-the-profiles-favorites-tab

Comment: I don't think the answer in the link is correct

Comment: If we are getting confused to figure out what is the real meaning of those features,  by itself it's already a good reason to pay attention on it's need. Or it can be taken off or should be more clear. +1

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @user7294900 read the link completely and you will see that 1) *The number next to the tab indicates how many posts have new answers since you last visited the tab.* and 2) *The highlighting means that the particular question has been changed since you last visited that tab.*

Comment: @CalvT븃 how "Sometimes I get 1 favorite in the tab, but no highlighted question"?

Comment: How many questions do you have favorited currently? It could be that there are 5 or 6 other answers in other questions that you never opened.

Comment: But **only 1 highlighted question** and you wrote: "The highlighting of each question within the tab happens when there has been activity such as an edit or a new answer."

Comment: @user7294900 Right, there could be errors or unexpected behavior there but I'm asking about answers in relation to the bounty indicator icon on the tab. The two might be totally unrelated in how they decide what/when to show.

Comment: @TylerH what's bounty have to do with favorite?

Comment: @user7294900 Sorry, it's just the name of the blue icon that the SO devs use because they were lazy. It's the same styling icon as the bounty icons, and still even has the name.

Comment: in the case where you have the blue 1 icon in the tab and no highlighted questions, do you see any highlighted questions by clicking the other sort options? (votes, newest, added, etc.)

Comment: no, I just checked