# What does the favorites (Bookmarks) number indicate?

Tags: discussion, support, design, bookmarks, activity-tab

N.B.: The "favorites" tab has been renamed to the "Bookmarks" tab.

---

I just added a question to my favorites and saw it in my profile like this:

[image: Image of profile]

There is a nice number 5 on top, but I only got a single favorite question. What does the number (5 in this case) indicate?

[This MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114277/388562) and [the MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) say:

> The number next to the tab indicates how many posts have new answers
> since you last visited the tab.

But either my basic math is wrong or that is wrong.

[Related MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363590/favorites-tab-is-showing-different-number-than-what-is-highlighted-in-list) (probably a duplicate, so feel free to shoot it down :) )

Comment: I think all answers, edits to answers and comments are counted.

Comment: @CodeCaster And what would be the starting point for counting? This image was imidiatly after I added the question as a favorite while the last activity (of any kind) was over 10 hours before.

Answer (score 5):

[Quote from Jeff Atwood (Co-founder of Stack Exchange)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3808/843029):

> if you favorite a question, you opt in to updates on that question and they will show in your `/recent/` and light up the envelope, just as if you own the question.

Comment: That explains the favorites *feature* in general, but [no one knows what the *number* actually indicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319449/253521)

Comment: @TylerH Based on Jeff's answer, I guess it means updates on bookmarked posts?

Comment: If that's all that counted, there wouldn't be confusion. The issue is that the number shown often does not match the number of updates made to a thread you've bookmarked. The number could show "5" for example and you only see one bookmarked thread with recent activity... and the only recent activity is a single edit to a single post. Just for one example.

Comment: @TylerH Hmm, that's weird, I've upvoted your referred post, hope they can fix this soon.