# Is the Bookmarks badge counter broken?

Tags: discussion, bug, bookmark

I just added my first bookmark, having finally figured out they are the best place to store all the dupes that I can never find to hammer with. Having added it, I then visited my Activity page only to find a count of `2` on the Bookmarks badge:

> [image]

Is the badge counter broken, or is there some reason why it shows `2` instead of `1`?

Comment: It shows a count of how many times a bookmarked Post has been active since you last looked at the tab... so I'm guessing that specific question has been active twice?

Comment: @Catija thanks - I guess that makes more sense than it being a count of the changes I made to my bookmarks list.

Comment: One of those actives was probably me a few days ago. That canonical answer has been at top of JS Frequent list for years but somebody angrily removed the javascript tag with comment " jQuery is not js". I rolled it back due to it's conceptual importance and because I couldn't find it where it has been for years

Comment: Duplicate of [What does the favorites number indicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372353/what-does-the-favorites-number-indicate). _“The number next to the tab indicates how many posts have new answers since you last visited the tab.”_.

Comment: @charlietfl I presume 1 was me bookmarking the answer, but I just did it an hour ago, so I wouldn't have thought it was your activity. Still with so many answers it's quite possible one of them saw some activity in the few minutes it took me to get around to the activity page.

Comment: @user4642212 that is indeed the same question but it doesn't have an answer...

Comment: @user4642212 that is definitely not the case here, as this post had **0** new answers between me bookmarking it and then viewing my activity page

Comment: @Nick Other activity counts as well. For example, there was a rollback 2 days ago. Bounties etc. count as well.

Comment: @user4642212 there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer as to what defines "activity" though. I don't mind my question being closed as a dupe, but it would be nice if one of the questions had an authoritative answer.